# change the sscene before deleting an object

Tags: python, scripting, objects

How can I perform some actions before deleting an object.

If I have an object that has a relation with some other objects in the scene. and the object was selected in the screen then deleted.

How can I perform some changes (in a python add on program) to the other objects before the object is really deleted?

Comment: Welcome Samer :) Please add details as to what you have tried and what you want to achieve. Might be a good idea to start with the tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour. Enjoy blender.se!

Comment: The python api does not provide event handlers for object deletions. All handlers available are listed [here](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_3/bpy.app.handlers.html)).